# wthin tn.write() are double parentheses

Tags: python, telnet

I have bash to run in python code tn.write()

```
tn.write("a=$(lr 2>logp.txt) \n")
```

when I run it will error

```
syntax error: `a=$' unexpected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run python code directly in your bash.
You need to do as follows:

```
python -c 'tn.write("a=$(lr 2>logp.txt) \n")'
```

You will encounter other errors, but not in the scope of your question.